# Passing mysql rows to scoring algorithm?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have this php algorithm ranking function(hacker news):

```
function calculate_score($votes, $item_hour_age, $gravity=1.8){
    return ($votes - 1) / pow(($item_hour_age+2), $gravity);
}
```

And I have this table in MySql:

```
post{id, post_text, votes, date}:
```

I was wondering how can I pass these MySql data parameters to that function, to determine the order they go in, PS. `$item_hour_age`, is how many hours the post is been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you already have $`votes`, so you only need to change $`date` into hours then:

```
 $item_hour_age = (time() - $date) / 60 / 60;   // minutes+seconds
```

Assemble the output in a result array and sort it:

```
 foreach ($pdo->fetchAll() as $article) {

     $score = calculate_score(...);

     $r[$score] = $article;
 }
 krsort($r);
```

Afterwards loop over the article list from $r and output them.

Comment: thanks, but how do i order my results using this funtion? when i pass the parameters

Comment: thats what i dont get, im new to php

Comment: See edit. Instead of `$pdo->fetchAll()` you might have to use the old mysql_fetch_array or whatever you are using to get your posts.

Comment: just one more question, how do i limit to display the best 10 articles

Comment: You need a counter in the output loop. Use `if ($n++ >= 10) { break; }` for simplicity. Works in for and while loops, but initialize `$n=0;` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your specs in details, but you could use a MySQL query.

Simple, and probably much faster in terms of CPU and memory, allowing possible results pagination (if you need it) with less PHP memory usage

> SELECT t.*, (`votes` -1) / POW( (DATE_DIFF(NOW(), `date`)), 1.8) as score
>   FROM table ORDER by score DESC

I supposed $item_hour_age it's the difference in days. You can easily use hours via a conversion to timestamps